# rails active record: update a table with join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on a rails project.
I have two tables storing data from disparate systems: tasks and projects.

With a condition, Projects knows Tasks through ref_id, but not in the opposite direction.
so, once matches found from a join, I'd like to set task.project_id with the matched Projects table's id.

```
UPDATE FROM task AS t
LEFT JOIN projects as p
ON t.ref_id = p.ref_id
SET t.project_id = p.id
```

my question here is: how can I achieve this using active record in rails?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using postgres you can run an `update_all` with a "join" from the model like:

`Task.connection.update_sql("UPDATE tasks AS t SET project_id = p.id FROM projects AS p WHERE t.ref_id = p.ref_id")`

Note: the `update_sql` call is deprecated for Rails 5 and should be switched to just `update`

Since you are sending sql directly you need to make sure you are using syntax appropriate for your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by passing your sql directly

```
Task.connection.update_sql("UPDATE FROM task AS t LEFT JOIN projects as p ON t.ref_id = #{p.ref_id} SET t.project_id = #{p.id}")
```